# Seleccionar y visualizar archivo tipo blob binario de base de datos SQL en Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, blob

Estoy intentando traer desde una base de datos en SQL un archivo tipo blob binario que es un pdf en realidad y poder visualizarlo desde una web que tengo en Ruby on Rails.
Lo que he intentado realizar es lo siguiente:

```
<%= results = FirebirdDBModel.connection.execute("select RESUMEN from PERSONA_CC_RESUMEN where PERSONA_ID=24") %>
  <% a = Affiliate.find_by_id(88) %>
  <% results.each do |file| %>
    <%= file[0] %>
<% end %>
```

Y el resultado que obtengo es lo siguiente: (lo adjunto en una imagen ya que es un conjunto de caracteres largo)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla a la que consulto esta en la siguiente imagen, lo que quiero visualizar en mi web es el campo RESUMEN que es el pdf que necesito mostrar en la web.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :affiliate_exceptions
  resources :exception_types
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  root to: 'pages#inside'
  #get 'inside', to: 'pages#inside', as: 'inside'

  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
  get '/authorisations/my_authorisations', to: 'authorisations#my_authorisations'

  get 'turns/turns_list', to: 'turns#turns_list'

  get 'admin/turns/check_turns', to: 'admin/turns#check_turns'

  get 'turns/todos', to: 'turns#todos'

  get '/authorisations/statistics', to: 'authorisations#statistics'

  get '/practices/out_of_average', to: 'practices#out_of_average'

  namespace :api do
    devise_for :users, skip: [:password, :confirmation, :unlock],
    controllers: {
      sessions: 'api/sessions',
      registrations: 'api/registrations'
    }

    namespace :v1 do
      get 'affiliate/active', to: 'affiliate#active'

      post 'users/associate', to: 'users#associate'

      resources :authorizations
    end
   match "*path", to: "errors#catch_404", via: :all
  end

  resources :affiliates, only: [:index, :show, :update]
  resources :agreements, only: [:index]
  resources :specialities
  resources :specility_practice_diagnoses

  resources :providers, only: [:index] do
    collection do
      get 'actives'
    end
    member do
      get 'agreements'
    end
    member do
      get 'specialities'
    end
  end

  # get '/practices/:id/value', to: 'practices#value'
  resources :practices, only: [:index] do
    member do
      get 'value'
    end
  end

  resources :authorisations do
    resources :items, controller: 'authorisation_practices'
    member do
      patch 'print'
    end
  end

  namespace :admin do
    root "base#index"
    get 'import_fail_logs/index'
    get 'import_fail_logs/remove_all'
    resources :turns
    resources :affiliate_types
    resources :diagnosis
    resources :people
    resources :providers
    resources :users    
    resources :affiliates do
      resources :plans, controller: 'affiliate_plans', except: [:show, :new]
    end
    resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy, :index]
    resources :agreements do
      get 'praxis', to: 'agreement_practices#index'
    end
    resources :agreement_practices
    resources :plans do
      resources :affiliates, controller: 'plan_affiliates', only: [:create, :destroy, :index]
    end
    resources :practice_coinsurances
    resources :provider_types
    resources :practices
    resources :affiliate_plans, only: [:edit, :update], as: "plans_affiliate"
    resources :affiliate_exceptions
    resources :exception_types
  end

  namespace :secretaries do
    resources :managements, except: [:edit, :update]
  end

  namespace :affiliates do
    resources :managements
  end

  resources :ctacte
  resources :consumo_grp
  resources :financiations, only: [:create, :index]
  
  resources :schedules
  resources :holidays
  resources :turns
  
    get 'turns/mostrar_turns', as: 'mostrar_turns'
    
    resources :calendars do
        resources :schedules
    end
    
    get 'turns/my_turns', as: 'my_turns'
    get 'turns/show', as: 'show'
   
end
```

Comment: Alguna posible solución?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada, tienes que crear un medio para descargar el archivo desde el servidor.
Implementa una ruta como:

```
get :download, constraints: { format: /pdf/ }
```

y el correspondiente action en el controlador donde uses [`send_data`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.5/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data) para descargar el archivo, algo como:

```
  def download
    results = FirebirdDBModel.connection.execute("select RESUMEN from PERSONA_CC_RESUMEN where PERSONA_ID=24")
    send_data(results.first[0], filename: 'resumen.pdf')
  end
```

Luego, si quieres visualizarlo dentro de la misma página es un poco más complejo. Podrías usar una librería como [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/), [Adobe PDF Embed](https://www.adobe.io/apis/documentcloud/dcsdk/pdf-embed.html). También puedes usar el visualizador de google drive embebido, aunque claro, accederás a un servicio externo que podría no ser necesariamente algo que desees para tu app.

```html
<embed src="https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=https://s23.q4cdn.com/202968100/files/doc_downloads/test.pdf" width="500" height="375">
```

(Para probar el ejemplo, luego de presionar "Ejecutar" has clic en el ícono[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí], que por alguna razón no funciona a la primera aquí en SOes)

Comment: Estimado muchas gracias por responder. Excelente ejemplo para poder guiarme. En cuanto al medio para descargar el archivo desde el servidor , donde se definiria?

Comment: Alli agregue mi archivo routes.rb para que te guies mejor

Comment: @francofernandez ni idea, tu sabes mejor que yo donde debería ir. Si piensas agregar el action a un controlador en particular ya creado, deberías anidarlos dentro de su definición `resources :tu_controlador`. Si quieres hacer un controlador aparte para las descargas, porque estarán relacionadas con diferentes partes de tu código, deberías crear un nuevo `resources`. Ahí ya entra a ser una decisión de diseño más que programática.

Comment: Muchas gracias @alterlagos me ha sido de mucha ayuda y he podido resolverlo con los ejemplos que me diste. Una vez mas me has salvado el dia. Abrazo!